# C - strcspn() function skipping over the longer strings in my array

Tags: c, for-loop

I am trying to write a short function which takes a user input and returns the location of such input from an array.

```
int main(){
char *deck[5] = {"1c", "4h", "7s", "10d"};
char *input[10];
scanf(" %c", &input);
    for (int x = 0; x < 53;){
        int check = strcspn(deck[x], input);
        if (check == 0){
            printf("%d", x);
            break;
        }
        else{
            x++;
            printf("why\n");
        }
    }
}
```

It works for the first three (1c, 4h, 7s) and returns 0, 1 and 2 respectively, but when I type in 10d the function just returns 0 - not even printing out "why".

Why does the loop return a 0 and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your loop is fragile because of the 53 when the array has 4 entries, but presumably that's because you removed many cards from the deck to make an MCVE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcspn` checks if the first string starts with any set of characters from the second string. When you type `10d` it will return 0 because the first string `"1c"` starts with a `'1'` which is the character you read with `scanf`. Maybe you should use `strcmp` or `strncmp` instead of `strspn`.

There are several more problems in your code:

`char *input[10];` is an array of 10 pointers (`char*`). You probably mean an array of characters (a string), e.g. `char input[10];`.

Format `%c` scans a single character only, not the whole string you type.
Maybe `fgets` followed by removing `'\n'` and `\r'` characters is sufficient to read your input.

The for loop can go beyond the end of the array. `x < 53` should probably be `x < 4`.

With warnings enabled the compiler would probably warn you about some of the problems in your code. General recommendations: Enable compiler warnings and fix them. Read the documentation of the functions you are using.

Comment: @CaseyPak It might be interesting for others to see your modified code that works now. And you might mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Note that the `&` in the `scanf()` is not required.